# Save data in Python and then read in C++

Tags: python, c++, serialization, deserialization

- I have some code in Python which generates a set of data structures (they may be represented by classes but no methods are needed).
- This data structures may be extended or added new structures in future
- I have some code in C++ on Android which knew about part of this data structures and their fields.
- The only way to pass data structures is through serialization to file and then deserialize them
- Binary format support is needed.
- Mature implementations in Python and C++ are needed. BSD, MIT, Apache licenses are preferred.
- Speed is not critical.

I have tried custom format but it is hard to extend it. 
SAX-like parsers are too low level for such task.

Comment: The most important factor here is the file format to be passed on - whether you need to create a proxy class on the other side or if you simply need to read data on the other side. For this, I will recommend to use either JSON or XML data format.

Comment: @Greg I have tried custom format, but it is not extendable.

Comment: @Ian It is expected to read data in a set of classes in specific way.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score 1):

The most important factor here is the file format to be passed on - whether you need to create a proxy class on the other side or if you simply need to read data on the other side, once the data format is known on the received side, the receiver side *should* know how to handle it.

Thus, it is best to use the data format which are well-known and widely used. Mostly for the reason of their widely-used virtue, such data formats would also normally have some 3rd party or build in library to help you creating your data structure files.

For this purpose, I will recommend you to use either JSON or XML data format. Python already have serializers for both:

- XML: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577268-python-data-structure-to-xml-serialization/
- JSON : https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html, http://www.diveintopython3.net/serializing.html, https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

You can also search some of other alternatives which I believe are also available apart from them.